# Display issues with 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04

Symptom:

Waking up from lock, or into the login screen, or anytime the external displays wake up, there is about a 30% chance of black screen of death and frozen computer resulting in me having to hard reboot my computer.

Hardware:

Thinkpad 480

Nvidia:

```
Thu Aug  9 08:54:26 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.48                 Driver Version: 390.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX150       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P0    N/A /  N/A |   1202MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1855      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           103MiB |
|    0      2453      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          49MiB |
|    0      3231      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           565MiB |
|    0      3581      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         229MiB |
|    0      5067      G   ...-token=054321E10AA659533AF9D7CF1C680106   116MiB |
|    0      6813      G   ...-token=A77B6F64CFBEA425929ADF8ED6CA7D36    74MiB |
|    0      6825      G   ...-token=C5D0893F365511906D78B3B2014F700E    63MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

gpu-manager:

```
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia module: nvidia-uvm.ko
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? yes
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:5917
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:1d10
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nvidia-drm"
Found "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "i915"
output 0:
    card1-DP-6
output 1:
    card1-eDP-1
output 2:
    card1-DP-5
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card1: 3
Does it require offloading? yes
last cards number = 2
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 2
Has the system changed? No
Intel IGP detected
Intel hybrid system
Nvidia driver version 390.48 detected
Creating /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf
```

Error:

```
[Thu Aug  9 08:48:20 2018] [drm:intel_mst_enable_dp [i915]] *ERROR* Timed out waiting for ACT sent
[Thu Aug  9 08:48:21 2018] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
[Thu Aug  9 08:48:41 2018] [drm:intel_mst_enable_dp [i915]] *ERROR* Timed out waiting for ACT sent
```

Thoughts:

i915 is my intel graphic card, which should never be used. I don't have bumblebee installed and I am using xserver, not wayland, which as far as I understand can only use one card and can't switch. I have purged the nvidia 390 drivers a few times and reinstalled. I have also tried the nvidia beta drivers, which made things much worse.

Comment: Searching AskUbuntu for [black screen 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=black+screen+18.04) I get 244 hits, about 30-40 of which have the same symptoms as you describe. Could you reference those with answers that you have already tried, and that did not work?

Comment: wow, that makes me sad, I can't believe how big this issue is